# Element onclick event does not show data

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following script to create some hyperlinks which are numbers stored in an array. I want to be able to click those numbers and get the particular number to be shown in the alert box. I am able to see the links but when I click them I don't see any data.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var str="732176086,732176085,735219154,735219155,23948614,23948629,23948628,764488973,764488974,764488975,23948631,732164301,732164304,732164305,732164303,732164302,732168040,832567989,832567988,807573121,807573120,765867299,831150154,831150153,23951065,23952295";
var str_array=str.split(',');

for(var i=0;i<str_array.length;i++)
{

controlRef = document.createElement('a');
var newLine=document.createElement('br');
document.body.appendChild(newLine);
    controlRef.href = '#';
    controlRef.innerHTML = str_array[i];
    document.body.appendChild(controlRef); 
}
    controlRef.onclick = function () { alert(controlRef.innerHTML); };


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the click handler inside of the `for` loop.

You also need to break the closure to `controlRef`. Otherwise the `controlRef` will point to the last element.

```
controlRef.onclick = (function(element) {
    return function() {
        alert(element.innerHTML);
    };
})(controlRef);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EsWpA/).

Comment: Thanks Alex but I can now  see the data  on the last index in the array  but how do I change it to see the data on whatever index I click on??